# AccessToken change

Tags: c#-4.0, facebook-graph-api

What kind of situation that can change the long-live access token? I get the access token by using offline_access scope. I'm asking this because I need to prepare for more function to be added into my system.

Answer (score 0):

When a user changes their password the offline_access tokens become invalid.

Answer (score 0):

This can become invalid if the user changes their password, or revokes some, or all, privileges from your application.